# Vuejs: You are mounting an instance with a template to `<body>`

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I got the following error:

vue.common.js?e881:987

> [Vue warn]: You are mounting an instance with a template to `<body>`. This will replace  entirely. You should probably use `replace: false` here.

I'm using `vue-webpack` template and vue-router:

Here's my `main.js`:

```
var Vue = require('vue');
var VueRouter = require('vue-router');

var App = require('./App');

Vue.use(VueRouter);

var router = new VueRouter();

router.map({
});

router.start(App, 'body');
```

So, where should I write the option `replace: false`?

`App.vue`:

```
<template>
    The site title is：{{html_title}}
    <div>
        <input v-model="parentMsg"/>
        <br/>

        <p>{{ parentMsg }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['html_title'],
        components: {},
        data: function () {
            return {
                parentMsg: 'test'
            };
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: When you're instantiating your Vue object. See here: https://vuejs.org/api/#replace.

Comment: @ManoDestra, but I'm using `router.start` rather than `new Vue()`, what should I do in my case?

Comment: You could perhaps, in that case, use a callback on router.start: http://vuejs.github.io/vue-router/en/api/start.html, to access the router.app after instantiation. These are just suggestions. I'm admittedly no expert.

Comment: you should add `replace: false` to the definition is App.vue - or simply not mount on the body tag, but a Wrapper div inside it.

Comment: @LinusBorg Could you please make an example?

Comment: Paste the code for App.vue, and I'll create an answer with the corrected code.

Comment: @LinusBorg, Thank you, it works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

App.vue should have the option `replace: false`

```
<script>
    export default {
        replace: false,
        props: ['html_title'],
        components: {},
        data: function () {
            return {
                parentMsg: 'test'
            };
        }
    }
</script>
```